# Прописная буква при употреблении только части имени учреждения

Tags: названия, прописная-строчная, ономастика

Добрый день. Имеется составное название учреждения, в котором только первое слово пишется с прописной буквы. Например, Высшая нормальная школа. Следует ли слово "школа" писать с прописной буквы, если оно используется без других слов? Например:

Он учился в Высшей нормальной школе. Уже через несколько лет после окончания он вернулся в эту Школу в качестве преподавателя.

Следует ли во втором предложении слово "школа" писать с прописной буквы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Школа должна писаться со строчной буквы.

Написание прописной буквы в усеченных названиях возможно только в ЧАСТНЫХ случаях.Это касается следующих написаний:

Государственный Литературный музей (Литературный музей),

Государственный Исторический музей (Исторический музей),

Государственный академический Большой театр (Большой театр),

Государственная Третьяковская галерея  (Третьяковская галерея).

В этом случае два  первых слова в составе имен собственных пишутся с прописной буквы, так как второе слово стоит в начале УСЕЧЕННОГО НАЗВАНИЯ и является БОЛЕЕ ИНФОРМАТИВНЫМ.

Comment: Розенталь объясняет это так: "С прописной буквы пишется (помимо первого слова и собственных имен) начальное слово той части, которая сама по себе употребляется в функции того же названия)". Но в последнем словаре Лопатина "Прописная или строчная" (2011) Государственный литературный музей и Государственный исторический музей. А откуда вы взяли формулировку об информативности слова, начинающего усеченное название?

Comment: Музеи не спешат подстраиваться под новую орфографию. Например, на сайте исторического музея приведена следующая информация: «После Октябрьской Революции музей стал именоваться Государственный Российский Исторический музей. С февраля 1921 года по сегодняшний день титульное название музея — Государственный Исторический музей». На официальном сайте Литературного музея  - Государственный Литературный музей .

Comment: Литературный музей – это главный, общий, центральный музей, и  этим он отличается, например,  от Литературного музея им. А. М, Горького. «Государственный» – это всего лишь форма собственности, в то время как Исторический музей, Литературный музей – это названия по существу. И формулировка об информативности усеченного названия взята не откуда-то, а просто соответствует здравому смыслу. И если дать общую оценку ситуации, то у Розенталя этого здравого смысла несравнимо больше, чем в лопатинской орфографии.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, надо со строчной буквы. Вы же пишете "вернулся в ЭТУ школу". Школа тут не собственное имя; заглавной буквы быть не должно.

Comment: мне тоже так кажется, но не могу нигде на этот счет найти правила